# React Native What api should I use to get Geolocation based on search

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

What API should I use to search a specific location and get returned the lat and long. I need to get this information so that I can get a user's location.

```
const searchLocation = async (location = searchText) => {
    let searchedLocation = location.nativeEvent.text;

    const response = await axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${searchedLocation}&key=${googleMapsApiKey}`);
    console.log('Response: ', response.data.results[0])
  }
```

The response gives me the `lat` and `long` the API is also expecting to get back the `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`. The response sends back the viewport. Is the viewport coordinates suppose to be used for `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`?

Answer (score 1):

For getting user current location you can use [@react-native-community/geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/geolocation) library.

use like this.

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => console.log(info));
```

you will get response like [image: this]

after getting this response you can call any reverse geocoding service like google maps, LocationIq, etc.
I will suggest locationIq its free for starters.

e.g pass latitude longitude you got from geolocation library to this function

```
const apiReverseLocation = (lat, lon) => {
  const key = '<your-api-key-here>';
  const api = `https://us1.locationiq.com/v1/reverse.php?key=${key}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&format=json`;
  const request = axios.get(api);
  request
    .then(res => {
     
    })
    .catch(err => {
     
    });
};
```

Comment: I updated the question. I have gotten this far. I need help figuring out the delta coordinates.

Comment: You can define your latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta by giving fix value initially